# How can i access error individual attributes in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, error-handling, aws-datasync

!! i Am new to go !!

I Am using the datasync API to start a task execution , that works with no issues. I Am struggling with the returned error struct, i want to acces individual elements but i can't seem to be a ble to do so.

for exemple in the following error i want to be able to access the content of **Message_**

```
2022/03/19 09:33:48 Sync called : 
InvalidRequestException: Unable to queue the task execution for task task-xxxxxxxxxxxx. The task already has another task execution exec-030b4a31dc2e33641 currently running or queued with identical Include and Exclude filter patterns. Please provide unique Include and Exclude filter patterns for the new task execution and try again.
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  ErrorCode: "DedupeFailed",
  Message_: "Unable to queue the task execution for task task-xxxxxxxxxx. The task already has another task execution exec-xxxxxxxxxx currently running or queued with identical Include and Exclude filter patterns. Please provide unique Include and Exclude filter patterns for the new task execution and try again."
}
```

Here is my working exemple :

```
    // Create datasync service client
    svc := datasync.New(sess)

    params := &datasync.StartTaskExecutionInput{
        TaskArn : aws.String("arn:aws:datasync:*******************************"),
    }

    // start task execution
    resp, err := svc.StartTaskExecution(params)

    //err = req.Send()

    if err == nil { // resp is now filled
        fmt.Println(resp)  // this outputs this { TaskExecutionArn: "arn:aws:datasync:xxxxxxxx:task/task-03ecb7728e984e36a/execution/exec-xxxxxxxxxx" }

    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        //fmt.Println(err.Message()) THIS DOES NOT WORK
        //fmt.Println(err.Message_)  THIS ALSO DOES NOT WORK
    }
```

If I do this `fmt.Println(err.Message())` or `this fmt.Println(err.Message_)` I get this `error  err.Message undefined (type error has no field or method Message) err.Message_ undefined (type error has no field or method Message_)`

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Errors in the AWS SDK for Go are often of the interface `awserr.Error` ([Code on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/aws/awserr/error.go)).

If you just want to have the message, you can do this:

```golang
resp, err := svc.StartTaskExecution(params)

if err != nil {
    if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        fmt.Println(awsErr.Message())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

First, there is a check if there is actually an error:

```golang
if err != nil {...}
```

Then, we try to cast the error to it's specific "type" `awserr.Error`:

```golang
err.(awserr.Error)
```

The return value of cast is the specific error `awsErr` and a `bool` to indicate if the cast worked or not (`ok`).

```golang
awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error)
```

The rest of the code is basically just checking, if `ok == true` and if that is the case you can access the errors fields like `Message`:

```golang
if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
    fmt.Println(awsErr.Message())
}
```

Otherwise, you just print the standard Go error message:

```golang
if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
    ...
} else {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: OK perfect thank you @Jens . One last thing to get the value out of the TaskExecutionArn from the resp as shown in my edit. i assume i would need to go the same route ?

Comment: You need to start reading the documention @Joseph. Otherwise, you are going to have a very hard time as a developer. To get the response from the response you can do `resp.TaskExecutionArn`. This can easily be figured out in the reference documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/datasync/#DataSync.StartTaskExecution

Comment: Trust me i did @jens, it's not that straight forward. for instane resp.TaskExecutionArn would result in 0xc0003124a0 and not the actual ARN. Appreciate your time

Comment: @Joseph You get the address of the `string` (e.g. `0xc0003124a0`) because `TaskExecutionArn` is a (address) pointer to the value in memory. To get the actual value (and not the address) use `*resp.TaskExecutionArn`.